# Should Commands always be a facade to domain models behavior in CQRS?

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

In a DDD-CQRS scenario, should my commands in the Application/Service layer always be just a facade to different aggregation methods? Or should commands retain business logic inside it (consequently transferring that logic from domain models to the commands)?

Answer (score 2):

Commands are best thought of as **Data Transfer Objects (DTO)** - they transport data and intentions from the external world into the domain. They are ***intentions*** because the domain then decides to let the command through to execute or discard if it violates domain invariants.

Commands seldom contain business logic. They may contain validations to ensure the command itself is being expressed correctly and that it contains all necessary data in the right format, but that's about it. They rarely know of aggregate structures or the domain - they are dumb transports.

In reality, commands turn out to be quite distinct from aggregate structures you will eventually arrive at. They may not even map to any single aggregate. Executing a command may mean invoking an aggregate's method as part of the request, but the action may soon be followed by additional transactions on other aggregates (through domain events raised during the initial transaction) to make the system eventually consistent.

As a rule, you should only place business logic in the domain layer (Aggregates, Entities, Value Objects, Domain Services, and Domain Events). It is a code smell if you observe domain logic anywhere else, and code needs to be refactored.